# Periodically update ContextBroker from an external API

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I installed a Fiware platform with ContextBroker and Cygnus. Everything is working properly. I would like ContextBroker to update itself automatically every hour, by fetching data from an API on an external server (API in JSON format that returns data with a GET request).

Is it possible ? How to do ?

Every hour:

- ContextBroker request to get weather data
- ContextBroker update "weather" entitie with the data returned

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Orion Context Broker expects context producers to push data.

The only case in which Orion pulls data is in [context provider scenarios](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/context_providers/index.html) and does only in a transient way, i.e. it gets the data from the context provider and sends to the client in the response but the data is not stored in the context database managed by Orion.

In addition, you could have a look to the [FIWARE Device Simulator](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-device-simulator). This is a powerful and flexible tool which allows to use `external` as a source of data, allow acting as a bridge between your source of data and Orion Context Broker. From [its documentation](https://fiware-device-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simulation-configuration-file/index.html):

> external: Information about an external source from which to load, to transform and to register data into a Context Broker instance.